# regular expressions: extract text between two markers

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write an Python parser to extract some information from html-pages.

It should extract text from between `<p itemprop="xxx">` and `</p>`

I use regular expression:

```
m = re.search(ur'p>(?P<text>[^<]*)</p>', html)
```

but it can't parse file if it is another tags between them. For example:

```
<p itemprop="xxx"> some text <br/> another text </p>
```

As I understood `[^<]` is exception only for one symbol. How to write "everything except `</p>`" ?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, such as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  Regex is not a suitable tool for this kind of parsing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/699864

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = re.search(ur'p>(?P<text>.*?)</p>', html)
```

This is a lazy match, it will match everything until `</p>`. You should also consider using an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which, after installation, can be used with [CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
m = soup.select('p[itemprop="xxx"]')
```

Comment: A small correction: `.*` is a greedy match. `.*?` is a non-greedy match. You have correctly specified `.*?`, but incorrectly described it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Never use regular expressions to parse HTML.

2) The following regular expression will work some of the time, on some HTML:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import re

pattern = ur'''
    (?imsx)             # ignore case, multiline, dot-matches-newline, verbose
    <p.*?>              # match first marker
    (?P<text>.*?)       # non-greedy match anything
    </p.*?>             # match second marker
'''

print re.findall(pattern, '<p>hello</p>')
print re.findall(pattern, '<p>hello</p> and <p>goodbye</p>')
print re.findall(pattern, 'before <p>hello</p> and <p><i>good</i>bye</p> after')
print re.findall(pattern, '<p itemprop="xxx"> some text <br/> another text </p>')
```

As another answer pointed out, `.*?` is the non-greedy pattern which matches any character.